# Using jQuery animate with border attribute

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!--<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></SCRIPT>-->
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></SCRIPT>
        <style type="text/css">
            #content {
                border:0px solid #ff9999;
                width:0px;
                height:0px;
                padding:3px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="Animate"/>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                $('#content')
                .animate({
                    "borderLeftWidth":"1px",
                    "height":"400px"

                },1000)
                .animate({
                    "borderBottomWidth":"1px",
                    "width":"400px"
                },1000)
                .animate({"borderRightWidth":"1px"
                },1000)
                .animate({"borderTopWidth":"1px"
                },1000)
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

I am trying to make something useful by using animate function of jQuery. So if you run my code you can see that border-left and border-bottom is generated continuously because I am increasing width and height as well. But after that border-right and border-top just pops up. I want them to be animated as left and bottom border. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're animating something from zero pixels, to one pixels, and to get an animation there has to be something in between. When going from no pixels to one pixel, how do you expect your screen to show 0.3 pixels? This is why the border just appears, from zero to one is just one step, and you can't really animate that!

Comment: So this is not possible then?Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Its not about animating the width of border.I want the border to make a square.Starting from a point and then increasing till it makes a square.

Comment: If you're thinking about something like the border starting to become visible at one point, then moving around the element like a growing snake thingy, that's not possible. Well, anything is possible, it's just not that easy!

Comment: hmm that's exactly what i have in mind.Anyways thanks.I will try it though by hook or by crook :)

Comment: It can be done, but not really with borders. You'd have to use elements, and position them exactly and then animate the width or height to get that effect, and as you might gather that will be some complicated stuff. There's a lot going on in CSS3 these days, but I have'nt really seen anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've found solution for you. Make the box with position relative, then put four div in "absolute", something like this:

**html:**

```
<div id="my_contents">
    <div id="border_top"></div>
    <div id="border_right"></div>
    <div id="border_bottom"></div>
    <div id="border_left"></div>
</div>
```

---

**css:**

```
#my_contents {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px
    height: 200px
}

#border_top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

#border_right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#border_bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#border_left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 200px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#border_top').animate({'width':'200px'}, 1200);
$('#border_right').delay(1200).animate({'height':'200px'}, 1200);
$('#border_bottom').delay(1800).animate({'left':'0'}, 1200);
$('#border_left').delay(2400).animate({'top':'0'}, 1200);
```

Hope this is what you mean :)